# MS SQL - yyyyDDmm date format in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, where-clause, datetime-format

How to use `WHERE` clause for `yyyyMMdd` date format if I need to filter rows, where is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm` datetime format?

For example: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date = '20140510'`

By the way, this example works for rows, where is `yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000` datetime format.

Comment: You need to cast order_date as date in this case so it will ignore the time value. CAST(order_date as date) = '20140510'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by converting the date time value like this:

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = '2014-09-04 15:52:00.000'
print CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date, 112)
```

you will get this console output:

```
20140904
```

So in your scenario you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), order_date, 112) = '20140510'
```

Comment: This works fine and it's easy to use in C# app in comparison to other answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use convert

```
@date = '20140510'
    SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date = CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8),@date ), 126)
```

> ```
> For more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.  This allows any indexes on `order_date` to be used, if you use `CAST` or `CONVERT` on `order_date` MSSQL will not be able to use your indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date >= '20140510' and order_date < '20140511'
```